# jQuery- Reposition div onclick to align with a table row

Tags: jquery, css, model-view-controller

As another post I've made noted, I don't have much experience with jQuery, and I apologize for that. What I'm trying to do seems fairly simple.

Overview:
I have a table wrapped in a div. Within that table, each row represents a distinct element. I have it setup such that when a link is clicked in each row, the corresponding data for that element is displayed in a div next to the table. This part works.

What I'm trying to do:
I would like the top of the popup div to display inline with the table row that is selected.

Here's my simplified code:

```
    <div id="container" style="display:inline-block">
       <table>
          <tr id="selected_row">
             <td>
                <a href="/gohere" onclick="updatePos('#param_detail_container');">
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
                </a>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </div>

    <div id="popupDiv" style="display:inline-block; position:absolute; ">
        Contenet in here...
    </div>
```

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function updatePos(popupDiv) {
          var top = $('#selected_row').offset().top;
             popupDiv.css({ top: top + "px" }).show();
          });
    </script>
```

I receive the following error:

```
    Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined
```

'replace' is located inside of jquery1.6.2.min.js. I'm assuming this has something to do with how I'm trying to set the top attribute of the popupDiv. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function must be global, so put it outside `ready`:

```
/*$(document).ready(function() {

});*/

function updatePos(popupDiv) {
      var top = $('#selected_row').offset().top;
      $(popupDiv).css({ top: top + "px" }).show();
   }
```

in your case no need to use `$(document).ready`

Comment: This seems to be what I need. Only problem is now when I click, it says that css is not a valid property of popupDiv.

Comment: that is because it should be $(popupDiv).css(...)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helped.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      function updatePos(popupDiv) {
         var top = String($('#selected_row').offset().top);
             $(popupDiv).css("top", top + "px").show();
         };
      });
</script>
```